# Merging Cells in Column Command Button Reset

Tags: vba, excel, merge, reset

I am new to vba and running into a problem. My code works so far when I click the command button for the first time. It gets data from one sheet and pastes it into the "TEST" sheet, sorts it from A-Z, and then merges the similar cells in column A. However, when I click the button again, the data changes because of the merged cells and the format messes up. I know I need some type of reset so when the button is clicked again, the code executes like clicking it for the first time. I'm not sure how to implement that and any feedback would be great. I highlighted the merge code section because I think that's where the reset may need to go

```
Sub Button1_Click() ' Update Button

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim lastRowPart As Long
Dim lastRowCW As Long
Dim lastRowQty As Long
Dim lastRowDescrip As Long

'1. Copies and formats data
lastRowPart = Sheets("Inventory Overview").Range("F" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
lastRowDescrip = Sheets("Inventory Overview").Range("G" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
lastRowQty = Sheets("Inventory Overview").Range("I" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
lastRowCW = Sheets("Inventory Overview").Range("L" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row

Sheets("TEST").Range("A2:A" & lastRowCW).Value = Sheets("Inventory Overview").Range("L2:L" & lastRowCW).Value
Sheets("TEST").Range("B2:B" & lastRowPart).Value = Sheets("Inventory Overview").Range("F2:F" & lastRowPart).Value
Sheets("TEST").Range("C2:C" & lastRowQty).Value = Sheets("Inventory Overview").Range("I2:I" & lastRowQty).Value
Sheets("TEST").Range("D2:D" & lastRowDescrip).Value = Sheets("Inventory Overview").Range("G2:G" & lastRowDescrip).Value
Sheets("TEST").Range("A1:A" & lastRowCW).Columns.AutoFit      
Sheets("TEST").Range("B1:B" & lastRowPart).Columns.AutoFit     
Sheets("TEST").Range("C1:C" & lastRowQty).Columns.AutoFit     
Sheets("TEST").Range("D1:D" & lastRowDescrip).Columns.AutoFit 

'2. Sort Cells
Dim sortSheet As Worksheet
Set sortSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TEST")
Dim LastRow As Long

LastRow = sortSheet.Cells(Rows.count, 4).End(xlUp).Row

With sortSheet.Sort  ' sorts data from A to Z
 .SetRange sortSheet.Range("A2:D" & LastRow)
 .Header = xlGuess
 .MatchCase = False
 .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
 .SortMethod = xlPinYin
 .Apply
End With

***'3. Merge CW Cells
   Dim rngMerge As Range, cell As Range, lastRowMerge As Long
   lastRowMerge = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
   Set rngMerge = Range("A1:A" & lastRowMerge)
  MergeAgain:
   For Each cell In rngMerge
    If cell.Value = cell.Offset(1, 0).Value And IsEmpty(cell) = False Then
        Range(cell, cell.Offset(1, 0)).Merge
        GoTo MergeAgain
    End If
Next***

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need before pasting is:

```
Sheets("TEST").Cells.UnMerge
```

This will UnMerge all cells in `Sheet("TEST")`. If you need to unmerge a specific range, then just use something like:

```
Sheets("TEST").Range("A1:H586").Unmerge
```

Answer (score 0):

This TEST sheet of yours. Is it always gonna be a clean sheet?
What is really the point of your routine?
You could always
Something like:

```
'This deletes te worksheet "TEST" and creates a new one with the same name
Set sortSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TEST")
sortSheet.Delete
set sortSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
wsSheet.name = "TEST"
```

Or you could just unmerge everything:

```
sortSheet.Range("A2:D" & cStr(lastRowDescrip)).UnMerge
```

Unmerging cells should take care of your problem.
Needless to say but all the lines above should come before copyying the data.